# Submitting dynamic inputs into database using POST method web api in JSON format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, xslt

i am currently working on a dynamic form builder( allows user to create whatever forms they want). Since its dynamic, i cant predict what the inputs will be as the question could be a checkbox and etc. Therefore, i wonder how do you exactly submit the form inputs to the database using post method web api in JSON format. Also, it has to be able to create a new table based on the tag . Sorry if its confusing, i am very new to this field and without any assistance.

The code below is the xml file for which the xslt will display it on the webpage as html.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<form>
  <display_name>In Store Hub Trooper Feedback Form</display_name>
  <form_theme>SkyBlue</form_theme>
  <show_score>True</show_score>
  <calculate>True</calculate>
  <db_table_name>form_for_hub_trooper_in_store_feedback_form_20160829174321</db_table_name>
  <fieldset>

    <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
      <question_title>Date of Audit</question_title>
      <type>DateOfAudit</type>
      <db_field_name>date_of_audit</db_field_name>
      <additional_comment/>
    </field>
    <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
      <question_title>Name of Auditor</question_title>
      <type>TextField</type>
      <db_field_name>name_of_auditor</db_field_name>
      <db_field_length>100</db_field_length>
      <db_field_type>string</db_field_type>
      <additional_comment/>
    </field>
    <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
      <question_title>Store Location</question_title>
      <type>TextField</type>
      <db_field_name>store_location</db_field_name>
      <db_field_type>string</db_field_type>
      <additional_comment/>
    </field>
    <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
      <question_title>Name of Staff</question_title>
      <type>TextField</type>
      <db_field_name>name_of_staff</db_field_name>
      <db_field_length>100</db_field_length>
      <db_field_type>string</db_field_type>
      <additional_comment/>
    </field>
    <group name="Basic Service Skills">
      <section name="Greet" db_field_name="greet_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Welcome customer with standard greeting</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>welcome_customer_with_standard_greeting_greet</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="1" id="Welcome customer with standard greetingyes" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="Welcome customer with standard greetingno" extratext="N">No</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>3</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
      <section name="Service Interaction" db_field_name="service_interaction_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Ask for customer's name politely</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            ask_for_customers_name_politely_service_interaction
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="Ask for customer's name politelyyes" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="Ask for customer's name politelyno" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="2" id="Ask for customer's name politelyno with reason" extratext="Y" >No with reason</item>

          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Understand and meet customer's needs</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            understand_and_meet_customers_needs_service_interaction
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="Understand and meet customer's needsyes" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="Understand and meet customer's needsno" extratext="N">No</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>3</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Active listening</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>active_listening_service_interaction</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="1" id="Active listeningyes" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="Active listeningno" extratext="N">No</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>3</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Address customer by name</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>address_customer_by_name_service_interaction</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="Address customer by nameyes" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="Address customer by nameavg" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0"  id="Address customer by namepoor" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
    </group>
    <group name="Security / PDPA">
      <section name="Control" db_field_name="control_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Verify customer's details when necessary</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>verify_customers_details_when_necessary_control</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="Verify customer's details when necessaryyes" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="Verify customer's details when necessaryno" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="2"  id="Verify customer's details when necessarynowithreason" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Display control over situation</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>display_control_over_situation_control</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="1" id="xzcasd" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="fshfusai" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="1" id="gcvilhuf8" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Proactive in probing for more details</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>proactive_in_probing_for_more_details_control</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="1" id="d8yfiwgdu" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="sdjfisdgfs" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="1" id="dsifyw" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
      <section name="Closing" db_field_name="closing_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Pre-closing</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>preclosing_closing</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="1" id="sdfietr" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="dfghvmdxsrw" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="1" id="jnvswoeirytu" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Thank customer with standard greeting</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>thank_customer_with_standard_greeting_closing</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="1" id="siyfh" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id=" jhvcb" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="1" id="hgfcfdsg" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
    </group>
    <group name="Temporary Absence">
      <section name="Explain for Absence" db_field_name="explain_for_absence_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Explain reason for temporary absence</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            explain_reason_for_temporary_absence_explain_for_absence
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="dfihsvbiw" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="yufeigvb" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="nfcjnvxiqeghe" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Thank customer for waiting upon return</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            thank_customer_for_waiting_upon_return_explain_for_absence
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="fdssdfsdxcvx" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="sdfsfsdxvxbn" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="fguydgfdsifdygfsbvxkvx" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
      <section name="Transfer Techniques" db_field_name="transfer_techniques_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Usher/direct customer when necessary</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            usherdirect_customer_when_necessary_transfer_techniques
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="1" id="sdfusdhfusfhsfsfhsgsd" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="euifhufdgafifort546" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="1" id="dsufidhsfbvsao87866484" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
    </group>
    <group name="Impression">
      <section name="Essential Courtesies" db_field_name="essential_courtesies_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Friendly and pleasant disposition</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            friendly_and_pleasant_disposition_essential_courtesies
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="duiahsadhsidhaduiacbx" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="dfsfstrtw5432" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="auidsheauhfiuaiuhae23422" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Eye contact / body language</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>eye_contact_body_language_essential_courtesies</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="aduyigta7e8o7wqtr3q785tr387q" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="34242dsfgbvcsdfsbg" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="uhrwerwh56484sfs6435" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Patience</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>patience_essential_courtesies</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="sdf8iohfsoihohs54352342dfsf" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="ufishduheorq03291df5s64" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="dsfidosjfdsifdshfspfs543242sda" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Display human touch</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>display_human_touch_essential_courtesies</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="dsfiuysfhgoisduf9328473248937432984" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="audhasduahdadiua7324632" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="uihfehrqueriqfgqe8942732" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Choice of words</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>choice_of_words_essential_courtesies</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="duriyrweorewyr798wer" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="ewr7ew8rytwe87rewyt8742873432g38" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="3894y242849y2hdsu9fdsh8" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Rate of speech / enunciation</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>rate_of_speech_enunciation_essential_courtesies</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="uirhewurwb42342uibfds" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="ajdnadjahd9o7342" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="ufdahdoisad9876983473" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Bad habits</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>bad_habits_essential_courtesies</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="aoidajoidjaw4253453" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="erwoiuhwroiuwher9842" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="ewrwihrewiurewr783432" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
      <section name="Grooming" db_field_name="grooming_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Well-groomed</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>wellgroomed_grooming</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="3" id="duhdaosp898342424" extratext="N">Good</item>
            <item score="1" id="aduhfuahbulhw432" extratext="N">Avg</item>
            <item score="0" id="udfhaoiauhyy987132" extratext="N">Poor</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>4</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
    </group>
    <group name="Business Competency">
      <section name="Business Knowledge" db_field_name="business_knowledge_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Give correct information for products or services</question_title>
          <type>DropDownList</type>
          <db_field_name>
            give_correct_information_for_products_or_services_business_knowledge
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="aduoiahsiuh4968586458496514" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="suihfsiufho7y467898" extratext="N">No</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>3</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N"  gotCode="Y">
          <question_title>What programming language is used below?</question_title>
          <codeQ>
     correct information for products or services What programming language is used below?
         </codeQ>


          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            retrieve_relevant_information_efficiently_business_knowledge
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="aduhsadiuah33y9o2313213" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="easdeqw412312" extratext="N">No</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>3</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Follow correct processes &amp; procedures</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            follow_correct_processes_procedures_business_knowledge
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="eqeqwdasavcxx523423" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="fdjfsoifjsoijoij7878787878785634543" extratext="N">No</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>3</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Update customer incident in system</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            update_customer_incident_in_system_business_knowledge
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="dadsaudhaduahuirhewrhiewur3243243241231465452131" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="dasbdaihgqiuhg4321313132131" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="2" id="wsjbsajbjnvu5235234675464-=" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
      <section name="Provide Solution" db_field_name="provide_solution_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Offer alternatives when needed</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>offer_alternatives_when_needed_provide_solution</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="1" id="asdadnbjnbvxxofi435435343" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="idfjsoifjdofsjfojfsfjsdfsa;jxjvnbvc,mnbj" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="1" id="sdlakda4564ad4a64w6e4wq5eq1eq" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
      <section name="Upsell / Retention" db_field_name="upsell_retention_score">
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Upsell value-added services / upgrades</question_title>
          <type>List</type>
          <db_field_name>
            upsell_valueadded_services_upgrades_upsell_retention
          </db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="sad1sad3sa1da5sda15a1d6awe4q8e623" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="dfdsfbhu34b2bw4b234" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="2" id="4u32h432u4h24j24h24j24h2b424b" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
        <field required="Y" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>Probe reasons for termination</question_title>
          <type>MultiLineTextField</type>
          <db_field_name>probe_reasons_for_termination_upsell_retention</db_field_name>

          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
      <section name="Resolution" db_field_name="resolution_score">
        <field required="N" is_admin_field="N">
          <question_title>First contact resolution</question_title>
          <type>MultiList</type>
          <db_field_name>first_contact_resolution_resolution</db_field_name>
          <options>
            <item score="2" id="b44b234j23bjdf9u9807" extratext="N">Yes</item>
            <item score="0" id="jbfejwbj53j423b4j2b5" extratext="N">No</item>
            <item score="2" id="ewjrhwueh6u235h234bjbr23242" extratext="Y">No with reason</item>
          </options>
          <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
          <additional_comment/>
        </field>
      </section>
    </group>
    <group name="Rate This Form!">
      <field is_admin_field="N" required="Y">
        <question_title>How would you rate this form?</question_title>
        <type>Drop</type>
        <db_field_name>How_would_you_rate_this_form_?</db_field_name>
      </field>
      <db_field_length>8</db_field_length>
      <additional_comment/>
    </group>
    <fail marks="5"/>
    <pass marks="10"/>
    <great marks="15"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: First I ensured that the dynamic controls will only be created in a specific div. then using jquery i got all the controls within this div and based on type wrote code to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

First I ensured that the dynamic controls will only be created in a specific div. then using jquery i got all the controls within this div and based on type wrote code to deal with them.

This is my div where all the controls are going to be created dynamically

```
<div id="controldiv">
</div>
```

As for my jquery code I got each control created and checked its type

```
function getval()
{
  var inputs = $("#controldiv input");
   inputs.each(function () {
     if (this.type == "text"){
       //get textbox val here
     }
      else  if (this.type == "checkbox"){
       // get val here
     }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do you move on from here?

Comment: send the values via ajax to backend

Comment: its not possible to get values of dynamically created controls in the backend without using javascript or jquery and ajax

Comment: Do you have a sample of it?

Comment: search how to create webservice in asp.net and how to do ajax request in jquery. the call the created webservice using the ajax request.

Comment: ok. however could you show me what do you mean by "//get textbox val here"?

Comment: var value=this.value;